# Angularjs error Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to display the configured values `author` and `version` in angular value service in html page.Version code is displayed fine but not the author name
Here is the html code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>
  <div>Author is : <span app-author></span></div>


  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the directive...

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
  directive('appVersion', ['version', function(version) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.text(version);
    };
  }])
  .directive('appAuthor', ['author', function(author) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs){
        elm.text(author);
    };
  }]);
```

And here is the service portion where `author` and `version` values are configured

```
    angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1')
  .value('author','JIM');
```

The error i'm getting in developer console is

```
Error: Unknown provider: authorProvider <- author <- appAuthorDirective
```

Comment: Even I was stuck in same issue, I fixed it yet I kept getting same issue. 
 Note that `function getService(serviceName, caller) {
      if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName))` 
After fixing issue **don't forget to do Ctrl+F5 to clear browser cache.**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure you are loading those modules (*myApp.services* and *myApp.directives*) as dependencies of your main app module, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives', 'myApp.services']);
```

**plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wxuFx6qOMfbuwPq1HqeM?p=preview

Comment: Well i'm loading those modules.but if dats the problem then how could version number get displayed and author not

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle with a replica of the problem? It could be a typo or some kind of collision on service names. (As you can see, on the one I've provided it is working correctly)

Comment: well i think u were i was missing to load some modules.Thanks dat helped :)

Answer (score 31):

bmleite has the correct answer about including the module.

If that is correct in your situation, you should also ensure that you are not redefining the modules in multiple files.

Remember:

```
angular.module('ModuleName', [])   // creates a module.

angular.module('ModuleName')       // gets you a pre-existing module.
```

So if you are extending a existing module, remember not to overwrite when trying to fetch it.

Comment: I had no idea that was the case. I was defining a variable and setting it equal to angular.module(...) after the angular-seed default ctrls, and was getting this same problem. Saved me much hair.

Comment: Excellent hint to search for `"angular.module('..', "` in a codebase to see where the module/'app' is created, thanks!

Comment: Wow! This is genius!