# angularjs Uncaught Error: Unknown provider:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I need some help out there.  I am learning Angularjs and trying to create a service.  Currently I am trying to separate everything in their modules.  When I create a new module called (bac.route-manager) and try to inject it in the app config as RouterService I get an error that I do not understand the meaning or how to fix it.  All my other stuff seems to work, except when I tried to add this module this unknown provider starts showing up only after I try to inject it.  Please any help is appreciated.

My error

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: RouterService from bac
```

My app.js file

```
angular.module('bac', [
   'bac.route-manager'
])

.config( function bacAppConfig( $routeProvider, RouterService ) {

     //I dont knwo if i can do this but right now it doesnt matter because of error
     console.log(RouterService.getRoutes());
});
```

My route-manager.js file

```
angular.module('bac.route-manager', [])

.service('RouterService', function() {

    this.getRoutes = function() {
        return {
                "/login": {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/login-manager/partials/login.tpl.html',
             requiredLogin: false
         },

        "/dashboard": {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/dashboard-manager/partials/dashboard.tpl.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            requiredLogin: true
         }

        };

};
```

});

I using grunt to generate the js includes in my html file but here is what that looks like with alot of stuff removed for brevity.

My index.html

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="bac">
    <body>
        <ng-view></ng-view>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app/modules/dashboard-manager/dashboard-manager.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app/modules/route-manager/route-manager.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try loading `route-manager.js` before `app.js`

Comment: I just tried that.  I generated the index.html file with grunt and then went in and manually moved the route-manager.js file above everything except the app.js file.  Still same error.  Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: RouterService from bac

Comment: @Codezilla The config and run phase is deferred until the whole document is loaded. The order in which they appear is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244272/angularjs-error-unknown-provider

Comment: @STARTRUNCMD Not a duplicate of that question since the `bac` module already define `bac.route-manager` as a dependency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `config` phase, the services declared are not available yet. Only those who have been declared using `provide` will through `serviceNameProvider` (add `Provider` after the name you have defined). For example:

```
.provide('RouterService', function() {
  var service = { };
  var routes = {
    "/login": {
      templateUrl: 'app/modules/login-manager/partials/login.tpl.html',
      requiredLogin: false
    }, 
    "/dashboard": {
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/dashboard-manager/partials/dashboard.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        requiredLogin: true
     }};

  service.getRoutes = function() { return routes; };

  this.$get = function() { return service; }

  this.setupRoute = function(data) { /* something here */ };
};
```

When you get a provider, all method defined on `this` will be available. When you access the normal service, what is injected is the return of the `$get` function. Depending on what you need, you either need to change your service to use `provide` or ask to be injected with the service in the `run` method:

```
angular.module('bac', ['bac.route-manager'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, RouterServiceProvider) {
    // Here, only RouterServiceProvider.setupRoute will be available
  }).run(function (RouterService) {
    // Here, the service singleton return with the $get function will
    // be injected
    console.log(RouterService.getRoutes());
});
```

**Edit**

As a side note, I believe that even if you have defined your `RouterService` as a `service`, asking for `RouterServiceProvider` would still work but no method will be present as `service` is essentially a wrapper around `provider` to only return the function in the `$get`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm going to re-factor and then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Converting the service to a provider works.  But I'm confused at how to implement the $get method.  Inside the provider I added a this.getRoutes() method so that I could next loop through the object to configure the routes in $routeProvider.  I don't really need a $get method at this stage, maybe later, but can't I just inject the RouterServiceProvider in a controller to use the this.getRoutes() method.